# Memory leaks looping through images to byte arrays

Tags: c#, image, memory-leaks, arrays

I have a  routine that scans a folder for images, then for each image, converts it to a thumbnail, and then uploads that thumbnail to a database. It will only run if there isn't any items for that particular folder in the db. My problem is I am receiving an out of memory exception after processing a couple of folders and I'm not sure where the leak is occurring. I have tried disposing of everything disposable that I can in the loop, but obviously something is still falling though the cracks.

```
private bool LoadImages(int folderid, int parentid) {
  ProgressScreen tfrm = new ProgressScreen();
  tfrm.Hide();
  DataTable mtable = new DataTable();
  List<FileInfo> lfile;
  mtable = Requests.ProcessSQLCommand(sqlconn, "Select f.ID, f.FolderName,f.FolderPath,f.ParentID,f.Root from Folders f where f.ID = " + folderid);
  DataTable ptable = Requests.ProcessSQLCommand(sqlconn, "Select Root from Folders where ID = " + parentid);
  if (ptable != null && ptable.Rows.Count > 0) {
    if (ptable.Rows[0]["Root"].ToString().ToLower() == "true") {
      return false;
    }
  }
  bool process = true;
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mtable.Rows[0]["FolderPath"].ToString());
  FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
  lfile = smFiles.ToList<FileInfo>();
  if (lfile.Count <= 0) {
    process = false;
  }
  if (process) {
    tfrm.Show(this);
    for (int c = 0; c < lfile.Count; c++) {
      if (((FileInfo)lfile[c]).Extension == ".txt") {
        lfile.RemoveAt(c);
      }
      if (((FileInfo)lfile[c]).FullName.ToLower().Contains("cover")) {
        lfile.RemoveAt(c);
      }
    }
      for (int b = 0; b < lfile.Count; b++) {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        this.Enabled = false;
        try {
          tfrm.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) - (tfrm.Width / 2), (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2) - (tfrm.Height / 2));
        } catch {
        }
        tfrm.SetProgress((int)(((double)(b + 1) / (double)lfile.Count) * 100), "Loading Images", lfile[b].Name.ToString());
        tfrm.Refresh();
        int recid = 0;
        DataTable ttable = Requests.ProcessSQLCommand(sqlconn, "Insert into Image (Name,FolderID,ParentID) VALUES ('" + lfile[b].Name + "'," + folderid + "," + parentid + ") Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
        if (ttable != null && ttable.Rows.Count > 0) {
          recid = int.Parse(ttable.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        }
        if (recid > 0) {
          Image timg = null;
          byte[] traw = new byte[0];
          traw = File.ReadAllBytes(lfile[b].FullName);
          MemoryStream tstream = new MemoryStream(traw);
          timg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(tstream);
          tstream.Dispose();
          timg = Requests.FixedSize(timg, 600, 600);
          tstream = new MemoryStream();
          timg.Save(tstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
          timg.Dispose();
          traw = new byte[0];
          traw = tstream.ToArray();
          tstream.Dispose();
          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlconn);
          con.Open();
          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update Image set [Thumb] = Convert(VarBinary(MAX),@Image) where ID = " + recid, con);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", traw);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Dispose();
        }
      }
    this.Enabled = true;
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    tfrm.Close();
    tfrm.Dispose();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.UseWaitCursor = false;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

the Fixed size method:

```
public static Image FixedSize(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height) {
  int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
  int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
  int sourceX = 0;
  int sourceY = 0;
  int destX = 0;
  int destY = 0;

  float nPercent = 0;
  float nPercentW = 0;
  float nPercentH = 0;

  nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
  nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
  if (nPercentH < nPercentW) {
    nPercent = nPercentH;
    destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
  } else {
    nPercent = nPercentW;
    destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
  }

  int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
  int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

  Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
  bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

  Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
  grPhoto.Clear(Color.Magenta);
  grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
  grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto, new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight), new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

  grPhoto.Dispose();
  return bmPhoto;
}
```

the original images (before fixed size) range anywhere from 2MB to 20MB, the image returned (max(len(image)) in the table is around 750 KB. (Edit: Corrected files sizes)

Number of images per folder ~100-150

I've looked and debugged, but cannot find what is causing the OOM issues, could someone point me at the error, or offer a better optimization for what I am doing?

Comment: you probably are not out of memory, but resources. there are lots of things there which should be disposed but may not be.  you can check via task manager looking at GDI object and handles.

Comment: FWIW, using [the `using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will clean up the code considerably

Comment: What are the dimensions of the largest image you have? Are you running this code in 32 bit? Does it always blow up on a specific image?

Comment: As @VikasGupta pointed out 100MB JPG is pretty much guaranteed to cause OOM (possibly even on x64) due to size of uncompressed images.

Comment: @VikasGupta largest image was 18.3MB 3744x6516x24b program is compiled for 64bit. No, it's not one specific image, it's usually after about 20 to 30 folders are processed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, was looking at uncompressed jpg sizes, edited the question with correct sizes.

Comment: @Plutonix from what I can tell, I've disposed of just about every disposable object in these two methods, but that is basically what I am asking, is if I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was a code review, there would be many things I'd suggest as improvements in this code...
But anyway, specifically to your question.. you memory leak is in following lines of code (please don't take it personally, but it was hard to spot, because the code is not as clean)

```
      timg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(tstream);
      tstream.Dispose();
      timg = Requests.FixedSize(timg, 600, 600);
      ....
      timg.Dispose();
```

You have **2** `timg` here.. one is original, and the second one is the one you get back from `Requests.FixedSize`. The `timg` you passed to `Requests.FixedSize` does **not** get disposed.

Comment: After about 100 folders it seems to be holding pretty well. Using Process Explorer, still seems to be something else leaking on other controls, but it is probably similar to what you found.